# Работа с Statement (Запустить БД в JAVA

Tags: java, база-данных

Я написал код который с помощью запроса MySQL выводит имена и фамилии всех студентов, но я хочу добавить еще один запрос который вызовет все их оценки.
Внизу код там я начал писать, но не получается дописать. Создал еще один statement под названием "stmtGetMarks" который выводит все оценки учеников из БД. Но не получается до конца его дописать. Можете помочь реализовать задачу. Просто нужно чтобы я мог в любой момент какой то из этих двух запросов вызвать.

Вот мой код который выводит все оценки в MySQL

```
SELECT pupil.name, pupil.surname, mark_value.values
FROM pupil, mark_value, mark
WHERE pupil.id = mark.pupil_id AND mark.mark_id = mark_value.id
```

А вот сам проект на JAVA

```
package sqltest;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class SQLtest {


    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school_db?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=GMT";
    private static final String user = "root";
    private static final String password = "123456";





    private static Connection con;
    private static PreparedStatement stmtGetStudent;

    private static PreparedStatement stmtGetMarks;
    private static ResultSet rs;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String query = "SELECT student.id, student.name ,student.surname from student";
        String query1 = "SELECT pupil.name, pupil.surname, mark_value.values\n" +
"    FROM pupil, mark_value, mark\n" +
"    WHERE pupil.id = mark.pupil_id AND mark.mark_id = mark_value.id ";

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

            stmtGetStudent = con.prepareStatement(query);
            stmtGetMarks = con.prepareStatement(query1);

            //stmtGetMarks.setString(1, "Vasya");
            //stmtGetMarks.setInt(2, 1234);
            // rs = stmtGetMarks.executeQuery();

            rs = stmtGetStudent.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt(1);
                String firstName = rs.getString(2);
                String lastName = rs.getString(3);



              System.out.println("Students :  " + firstName + " " + lastName);
            }

        } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
            sqlEx.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            try { con.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { }
            try { stmt.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { }
            try { rs.close(); } catch(SQLException se) {  }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Может стоит сделать один метод, который возвращает студентов (запрос query) и второй метод, аналогичного содержания, который будет выводить их оценки (запрос query1)? К тому же, как правило требуются оценки не вообще всех, а какого-то конкретного студента.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Определенно начать стоит с разбиения функционала на методы. Например, вот так

```
public class SQLtest {
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school_db?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=GMT";
    private static final String USER = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "123456";
    private static final String GET_ALL_STUDENTS_QUERY = "SELECT student.id, student.name, student.surname from student";
    private static final String GET_ALL_MARKS_QUERY = "SELECT pupil.name, pupil.surname, mark_value.values\n"
            + "    FROM pupil, mark_value, mark\n"
            + "    WHERE pupil.id = mark.pupil_id AND mark.mark_id = mark_value.id ";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SQLtest sqltest = new SQLtest();
        sqltest.printAllStudents(); // Напечатает всех студентов
        sqltest.printAllMarks(); // Напечатает все оценки
    }

    private void printAllStudents() {
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD)) {
            PreparedStatement stmtGetStudents = con.prepareStatement(GET_ALL_STUDENTS_QUERY);
            ResultSet rs = stmtGetStudents.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt(1);
                String firstName = rs.getString(2);
                String lastName = rs.getString(3);
                System.out.println("Students :  " + firstName + " " + lastName);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Ошибка при выборке студентов. " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void printAllMarks() {
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD)) {
            PreparedStatement stmtGetMarks = con.prepareStatement(GET_ALL_MARKS_QUERY);
            ResultSet rs = stmtGetMarks.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                String name = rs.getString(1);
                String surName = rs.getString(2);
                String value = rs.getString(3);
                System.out.println(name + "  " + surName + " " + value);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Ошибка при выборке оценок. " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Ну а дальше - дорабатывать исходя из потребностей. Например:

- Не выводить на экран студентов прямо в методе, а возвращать их в виде списка. Это потребует создания для студента отдельного класса.
- Параметризировать запрос на вывод оценок, а следовательно и метод. Например, передавать в метод идентификатор студента.
- Возвращать в методе вывода оценок список оценок вместо его непосредственного вывода на экран.